# Why declaring count variable globally produce wrong o/p for inversion count of array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

**This is code for counting inversions of array to be sorted. When count variable is declared globally and updated each time during merge, it produces wrong o/p.**

```
class Inversion_of_Array
{
    // arr[]: Input Array
    // N : Size of the Array arr[]
    static long count=0L;
    static long inversionCount(long arr[], long N)
    {
        // Your Code Here
        if(N==1)
            return 0L;
            
        countInversions(arr,0,arr.length-1);
        return count;
    }
    
    public static void countInversions(long[] a,int low,int high)
    {
        if(low<high)
        {
            int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
            countInversions(a,low,mid);
            countInversions(a,mid+1,high);
            crossInversions(a,low,mid,high);
        }
    }
    public static void crossInversions(long a[],int low,int mid,int high)
    {
        int n1=mid-low+1;
        int n2=high-mid;
        long l[]=new long[n1];
        long r[]=new long[n2];
        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
          l[i]=a[low+i];
        for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
          r[i]=a[mid+1+i];
          
        int left=0,right=0,k=low;
        while(left<n1 && right<n2)
        {
            if(l[left]<=r[right])
            a[k++]=l[left++];
            else
            {
               count+=(n1-left);
               a[k++]=r[right++];
            }
        }
        while(left<n1)
        a[k++]=l[left++];
        while(right<n2)
        a[k++]=r[right++];
     
    }
}
```

**But when we calculate inversions of left subarray ,right subarray and merge process and add them together it produces right o/p. Why it does not produce right o/p in above code?**

```
class Inversion_of_Array
{
    // arr[]: Input Array
    // N : Size of the Array arr[]
    static long inversionCount(long arr[], long N)
    {
        // Your Code Here
        if(N==1)
            return 0L;
            
        return countInversions(arr,0,arr.length-1);
    }
    
    public static long countInversions(long[] a,int low,int high)
    {
        long count=0;
        if(low<high)
        {
            int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
            count+=countInversions(a,low,mid);
            count+=countInversions(a,mid+1,high);
            count+=crossInversions(a,low,mid,high);
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static long crossInversions(long a[],int low,int mid,int high)
    {
        int n1=mid-low+1;
        int n2=high-mid;
        long l[]=new long[n1];
        long r[]=new long[n2];
        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
          l[i]=a[low+i];
        for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
          r[i]=a[mid+1+i];
          
        long ans=0;  
        int left=0,right=0,k=low;
        while(left<n1 && right<n2)
        {
            if(l[left]<=r[right])
            a[k++]=l[left++];
            else
            {
               ans+=(n1-left);
               a[k++]=r[right++];
            }
        }
        while(left<n1)
        a[k++]=l[left++];
        while(right<n2)
        a[k++]=r[right++];
        
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only changing `count` in one line in the topmost code sample, in `count+=(n1-left);`. and then you are returning that global variable in your method. Obviously, both code samples are not equivalent because they count vastly different things.

Comment: But merge method is called every time we merge two sub arrays and that's what ,when we count number of swaps required.